# How do I change nameservers on azure domain?

Tags: azure, cpanel, domain-name, nameservers

I have a domain registered with azure. I want to change the name servers so that it would point to my another server which contains cpanel hosting. I have tried changing the dns records but it didn't work. Is there any other way I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot cannot remove or modify the pre-populated Azure DNS name servers.

You can add additional name servers to this NS record set, to support co-hosting domains with more than one DNS provider.

This applies only to the NS record set at the zone apex. Other NS record sets in your zone (as used to delegate child zones) can be created, modified, and deleted without constraint.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-zones-records#ns-records

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have already tried adding the name servers but it didn’t work.

Comment: Did you get any error while adding additional NS records?

Comment: May you please describe in more details, add screenshots, what exact does not work?